# Homeoarchy en français

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire, typographie

En anglais, le terme « [homeoarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_criticism#Internal_evidence) » désigne le fait que deux lignes consécutives d'un texte commencent par le même mot, amenant le copiste (ou le lecteur) à sauter une ligne à la lecture :

[image]

Quel est le terme français équivalent ?

Comment: Est-ce qu'amener le lecteur à sauter une ligne est une volonté de celui qui écrit le texte?

Comment: J'ai ajouté un exemple pour clarifier.

Answer (score 7):

[Ce document](http://www.sources-chretiennes.mom.fr/upload/doc/Cours_paleo_grecque.pdf) donne à l'erreur de copiste qui consiste à sauter une ligne parce que des mots sont similaire le nom de "saut du même au même". Elle ne fait toutefois pas spécifiquement la distinction entre *ses sources* possibles ("homéoarctons" ou "homémotéleutes" [sic!]). Une recherche rapide indique que le terme "saut du même au même" est en usage (et cela [même en anglais](http://nestorscup.blogspot.ca/2006/12/west-on-textual-discrepancy.html)) et que les termes qui s'appliquent normalement aux deux figures de style semblent aussi en usage pour décrire les deux formes de l'erreur.

Answer (score 6):

À voir les premières références sur Google, il s'agit d'un terme technique en critique textuelle et le contexte est l'établissement d'une version de référence d'un texte dont on a que des copies. Est-ce que le terme est sorti de ce domaine ?

Je tenterais bien « homéoarchie », le terme anglais ressemble<sup>1</sup> à un terme savant aux racines grecques, mais d'une part si je vois bien pourquoi dériver de [*ὅμοιος*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%85%CE%BC%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BF%CF%82) (qui dans les dérivés que je connais indique la similitude), je ne vois pas ce que viens faire [*ἀρχός*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CF%81%CF%87%CF%8C%CF%82) (que je ne vois utilisé dans des dérivés que pour indiquer la détention du pouvoir, ce qui fait qu'« homéoarchie » sonne comme un régime politique au côté d'oligarchie), et d'autre part la seule occurrence que trouve Google ne me semble pas liée.

---

(1) J'ai pas trouvé de sources donnant l'étymologie du terme anglais.

Comment: Outre comme tu dis le fait que c'est un terme technique dérivé directement du grec, on dit [homéotéleute](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom%C3%A9ot%C3%A9leute) pour l'analogue en fin de mot. Étymologiquement, [αρχω](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%87%CF%89) peut signifier commander où être premier, commencer (même rapprochement sémantique que *princeps*, *leader*, ...).

Comment: @Gilles: non justement, une homéotéleute est l'analogue d'une anaphore (cf. mon commentaire à la réponse de Joubarc).

Comment: @Gilles: cela dit, [l'article sur Wikipedia en anglais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_criticism#Internal_evidence) indique "homeoteleuton" comme analogue à "homeoarchy", mais l'article dédié [fait une différence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoioteleuton#Scribal_error) entre la figure de style et l'erreur du scribe.

Comment: @Gilles, je veux bien qu'on peut trouver une explication, mais le problème est que tous les dérivés d'ἀρχός auxquels je pense sont liés à l'exercice du pouvoir.  « Homéoarchie » sonne comme un régime politique, pas comme un procédé de corruption de textes.

Comment: @Unfrancophone qu'on puisse

Comment: En critique textuelle, un homéotéleute désigne bien un saut du même au même (ce terme est le plus employé en français) en fin de ligne; pour l'équivalent en début de ligne, on ne trouve guère en français «homéoarchie» à ma connaissance, mais plutôt «homeoarcton» (cf. F. Duval, Les Mots de l'édition de textes, 2015, p. 60).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteCamps, je crois que ça mérite une réponse plutôt qu'un commentaire sous la mienne (voir aussi la réponse de @Circeus)

Answer (score 2):

La figure de style correspondante est une *[anaphore](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphore_%28rh%C3%A9torique%29)*, mais je ne sais pas si il existe un autre terme précis dans le cas où on cherche à mettre en évidence le risque de sauter une ligne.

Comment: Une anaphore est une figure de style volontaire qui consiste à répéter un mot en début de phrase (ou de proposition). Ma question porte sur la répétition involontaire d'un mot au début de deux *lignes* consécutives (qui ne sont pas forcément des propositions différentes).

Comment: OK — au vu de l'exemple et de tes explications, ma réponse n'est clairement pas la bonne. Je la laisse pour le moment, histoire que personne d'autre ne réponde la même bêtise.

Comment: Traduttore, traditore!

Answer (score 0):

Dans [Dictionnaire des typographes](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_l%27argot_des_typographes#A):

> **Avaro**
>       s. m. *Avanie*, et aussi accident. Nous orthographions ce mot à tout hasard. Quelle en est l’origine ? Nous l’ignorons. Peut-être vient-il d’avarie.

Comment: Y a-t-il une référence quant à la signification de ce mot? Je ne vois qu'une note concernant son orthographe, mais rien qui fasse penser qu'il s'agisse du mot que je recherche.

Comment: http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avaro (source http://www.gutenberg.org/files/18024/18024-8.txt) confirme l'orthographe, le sens et précise : argot, vieilli, rare - Il s'agit donc bien de l'argot des typographes, quelque chose d'involontaire qui apparaît à l'épreuve. Ce n'est pas une erreur en soi, tout est correct par ailleurs, hormis le confort de lecture.

Comment: D'après ces deux sources, "avaro" signifie "accident". Je ne vois aucune indication que cela désigne spécifiquement un accident d'alignement fortuit de caractères identiques dans un texte...

Comment: Avaro peut se comprendre : "Et Dédé, il va bien? - il a eu un avaro - grave ? -.." ou alors au moment de la lecture de l'épreuve : "Ah! un avaro, un *faux bourdon* .." . Bourdon signifiant une 'bourde' typographique par manque de lettre(s) dans un mot, un faux bourdon (toujours en environnement argotique ou populaire, le faux bourdon est une sorte de grosse abeille qui pique, alors que le bourdon [le mâle de l'abeille] ne pique pratiquement jamais) est donc une composition qui "pique" le regard, sans être une faute de composition . Je continue mes recherches sur homéoarchie -> usages typo

Comment: Je comprend bien comment ça pourrait s'utiliser, mais je ne vois aucune source qui appuie cette utilisation...

Comment: Bien d'accord - *faux bourdon, avaro typographique* (qui ne concernerait que les avanies de présentation, sans autre erreur) peut être un biais que ma mémoire produit, et que je ne veux vérifier : tous les artisans utilisant encore ce type de machine ont disparu de mon quartier, ceux qui ont pratiqué la typo sont à la retraite (voire au Père Lachaise). Je ne pourrais pas vérifier rapidement chez les vendeurs de livres anciens. Mais je ne lâche pas l'idée de trouver (ce n'est pas un problème de point, vous avez seulement aiguisé ma curiosité, .. et je vous en remercie)

Comment: sur http://www.fornax.fr/search.php les mots commençant par homeo* ou homéo* sont inconnus